# Is there a way to add a custom automated text (like a content table)

Tags: microsoft-word, automation, microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010. I'm typing down my maths notes, however we've got quite a lot of standard quotable equations. I would like to write them in an Appendix apart from the main content. Is there a way to achieve this automatically?

So far, Google has returned "how to create a table of contents" or using the field tool with StyleRef however that only searches the same page.

Thanks

Comment: Some clarification please. Do you mean that you want to enter equations in the main body of your document, then to create a "table of equations" in an appendix, with the full equation text (I.e. Not just captions)? Or do you want a table of equations in the appendix that you can reference in the body?

Comment: @bibadia I want to enter the equations in the main body of text, then create something that works like the table of contents, i.e. It is automatically filled in, and it is dynamic, however without the page numbers in an appendix with the full equation text.

Comment: I don't think any of the standard field-based mechanisms is going to work for you. TOC fields will and INDEX fields "flatten" the equation content - the closest I can get is to use a TC/XE field to insert a copy of the equation text. Then the TOC/INDEX field includes an equation object, but the text in it is neither the equation nor the linear format version. I'll provide an Answer that might be workable using fields, but (a) it's not entirely automatic and (b) it imposes some layout constraints on your equations. Anything else would require VBA or .NET code IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have assigned a style for your equations and that each equation is on its own line.  Have you tried inserting a Table of Figures at the end?

Comment: Thanks for this. This was just what I was looking for. I simply arranged some options to select the style and show them without a caption number and without a page number and the final result was just what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: except I just noticed that fractions and powers don't come out the same, instead of b/c I get bc and instead of a^3 I get a3 ... any ideas on how to solve this issue apart from typing them manually?

Comment: changing them to linear helps, however I prefer them to be in the professional format

Comment: FWIW the loss of formatting is why I didn't suggest this - the approach actually works better with the old equation editor where the ToF shows an image of each equation.

Comment: Have tried a field switch to address the formatting?  I'm checking it out now and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I think end notes may help you out.  Reference tab > insert end note.  I places an annotation where ever you are in the document and then drops you to the end of the document to add content, its just a footnote that shows up at the end of the document instead of at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It doesn't do what I want though. The endnote simply creates a link at the end of the page. I want something like a table of contents (however not a table of contents). The table of contents searches for text with the style "Heading" and automatically places that text in it. I want something that automatically places text found with a certain criteria (style is best I think) to be placed in a field where I place it (like you can place the TOC field anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach based on fields. But you can't use the "Display format" if you do it this way, and there's a certain amount of manual effort.

What you do:

For each equation, you insert the following nested fields:

```
{ SET { QUOTE eq{ SEQ eq } } "the equation" }{ REF { QUOTE eq{ SEQ eq \c } } }
```

(All the {} pairs have to be the special "field brace" characters that you can insert in Windows Word using ctrl-F9).

To insert the equation into the nested SET field, you first create the equation outside the SET field, then copy/paste it between the double-quotation characters in the field, then delete any surrounding text.

In your appendix, at the beginning you put

```
{ SEQ eq \r0 \h }
```

Then, in separate paragraphs, you put as many copies of the following nested field as you have equations:

```
{ REF { QUOTE eq{ SEQ eq } } \h }
```

Whenever you want to update your appendix, you'll need to maintain the count, then select the entire document, press ctrl-A, then F9 to update all the SEQ, SET and REF fields.

This gives you a "copy" of each equation in the appendix with a REF-type hyperlink to the original equation. If you wanted to include some kind of quotation numbering, I think that could be done but you would need to be specific about what you needed.

My suspicion is that the only way you will be able to do this kind of thing while allowing full Display format would be to use VBA (or, e.g, some .NET code) to recreate the appendix.

Comment: thanks for this however it involves too much manual effort for the actual document like you said

Comment: In that case I think you would have to resort to VBA or .NET code to do it without the problems mentioned in response to the "Table of Figures" suggestion - but maybe that was actually enough for your needs anyway?